I have a Geekom keyboard and have issues typing
I am running:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
My new Geekom keyboard keeps sticking sticking randomly. So characters will sometimes repeat like thissssssss.
Geekom support have suggested the keyboard drive might be faulty.  Can you advise please?
